# Streaming an uploaded file to an HTTP request

Tags: node.js, express, node-request, busboy, wistia

My goal is to accept an uploaded file and stream it to [Wistia](http://wistia.com/) using the [the Wistia Upload API](http://wistia.com/doc/upload-api). I need to be able to add fields to the HTTP request, and I don't want the file to touch the disk. I'm using [Node](https://nodejs.org/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [Request](https://github.com/request/request), and [Busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy).

The code below has two `console.log` statements. The first returns `[Error: not implemented]` and the second returns `[Error: form-data: not implemented]`. I'm new to streaming in Node, so I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
app.use("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    var writeStream = new stream.Writable();
    writeStream.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: req.headers});
    busboy.on("file", function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        file.on("data", function(data) {
            writeStream.write(data);
        });
        file.on("end", function() {
            request.post({
                url: "https://upload.wistia.com",
                formData: {
                    api_password: "abc123",
                    file: new stream.Readable(writeStream)
                }
            }, function(error, response, body) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not to familiar with the busboy module, but there errors you are getting are from attempting to use un-implemented streams. Whenever you create a new readable or writable stream directly from the `stream` module you have to create the `_read` and `_write` methods respectively [Stream Implementors (node.js api)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementors). To give you something to work with the following example is using `multer` for handling multipart requests, I think you'll find multer is easier to use than busboy.

```
var app = require('express')();
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
app.use(multer());

app.post("/upload", function(req, res, next) {
    // create a read stream
    var readable = fs.createReadStream(req.files.myfile.path);
    request.post({
        url: "https://upload.wistia.com",
        formData: {
            api_password: "abc123",
            file: readable
        }    
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        // send something to client
    })
});
```

I hope this helps unfortunately I am not familiar with busboy, but this should work with multer, and as I said before there problem is just that you are using un-implemented streams I'm sure there is a way to configure this operation with busboy if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like multer is built on top of busboy, so I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks again. I hadn't seen multer before—it's very nice. I was hoping to stream straight from the incoming request to the outgoing request (without storing the whole file in memory), but I'm not sure that's even possible. Multer at least has the `inMemory` option, but I'm not sure how safe this is. I'll probably just write the file to disk, but thanks for the tips.

Comment: Ya I misread and just saw you were looking for an off disk approach. I have personally not tried the `inMemory` option, hope it works out.

Comment: @DavidJones It's been awhile but I'm now exploring this idea as well. What did you end up deciding? Is it crazy to hold several MB files in memory instead of writing to disk?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use multipart (another npm) here is a tutorial:
http://qnimate.com/stream-file-uploads-to-storage-server-in-node-js/

Comment: Your answer is based on an URL. That URL has now broken.